# Generate two distributions of data with consistent differences in quantile values

Tags: random-generation, quantiles

How can one generate two sets of data which are different at each quantile values (say decile)? Ex: 10th & 80th percentile is 4 & 22 respectively for the first set and the same should be 8 & 44 for second set which implies the second set has larger values at each quantile.

If I can generate such data, I am planning to compare the performance of quantile regression in estimating each quantile value taking a binary predictor with values indicating each dataset.

I am specifically looking to generate data like this using R software.

Comment: Many sets of data are consistent with reduction to the same deciles, so this isn't a well-posed problem. Explaining why you think this is needed, or a good idea, might elicit better answers.

Comment: @NickCox I have edited the question with relevant details. I hope that helps. Could you please elaborate the statement "many sets are consistent..."

Comment: My statement is on all fours with pointing out that giving a median does not allow you to reconstruct the data uniquely; nor does giving a median and quartiles; and so on and so forth. Here is some role reversal. For a variable I have on my computer 10(10)90% points are  93.02, 182.25, 238.70, 337.45, etc. Now any data set whose quantile function intersects those points is a solution. Why not just some real data directly? Or simulated data from a specified distribution?

Comment: Adding to @NickCox 's point.  For your example, where the deciles of one variable are double those of the other, you could have two uniform distributions, two normals, one normal and one uniform, or pretty much any other "standard" distributions, or, of course, variables that are not well fit by any standard distribution.

Comment: Since you do not mention independence, you can generate the first dataset and then derive the second dataset by adding a uniform noise to each observation. Anyway, using a single continuous distribution, the probability that you get the same deciles on two randomly generated datasets is zero.